# starting Jenkins with runas

Tags: services, jenkins, privileges

I am trying to start Jenkins service but via CMD. This service requires specific credentials, because I set up Jenkins to run only with specific account, not as local system account. When I type:

```
runas /profile /user:user_1 "net start Jenkins"
```

CMD asks me for password so I type it correctly - when I typed incorrect one for test I received

```
1326: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

However even when I type correct user and password I get

```
Attempting to start net start Jenkins as user "Z1\user_1" ...
```

and uknown window seems to appear for a split second. When I open services it shows that Jenkins hasn't started. How can I run specific services that requires credentials from cmd? I know I can run CMD as administrator, but I would like to know another way.

Comment: You are trying to approach this as if it is *nix.  It is not.  In windows, you don't spawn a service like this.  You ask the [service control manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Control_Manager) to spawn one for you.  In windows,  the user that a particular service runs as is controlled by the service control manager and your service registration, not you simply spawning a process AS some user.  Windows has a way of dealing with an [entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-entry-point) that is different than a standard application.

Comment: Hrm.. I should read more before typing.  In windows, your service registration controls who something runs as.  Change the user in the service registration and use `net start` to spawn it.  Use the Computer Management console -> Services to change your user.

Comment: I do not understand you completely but it is possible to run service from cmd with "net start SERVICE_NAME" however Jenkins requires to be started with administrator account on my computer.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to open cmd window as administrator from cmd window if I am logged in to my computer as administrator. If cmd is opened in administrator mode it is enough to type "net start Jenkins" and no access is denied

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869311/start-stop-and-restart-jenkins-service-on-windows) post on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you. This is another way, but User Account Control window appears when using this exe. I would like to automate it so no window should appear.